# How to simplify this replace query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to change values for several specific reporting years, so this means I have to run each set statement separately with this query I currently have:

```
update [Table1]
set [Report Year] = replace([Report Year], '2013 LTP', '2013')
set [Report Year] = replace([Report Year], '2014 LTP', '2014')
set [Report Year] = replace([Report Year], '2015 LTP', '2015')
set [Report Year] = replace([Report Year], '2016 LTP', '2016')
set [Report Year] = replace([Report Year], '2017 LTP', '2017')
set [Report Year] = replace([Report Year], '2018 LTP', '2018')
```

Basically, I'm trying to remove LTP from years less than 2019.

Is there a way I can execute a query at once that does the same thing?
In other words, how can I simplify the update query I have?

### Edit

I need to do this for several tables, so say Table1 and Table2.

Table1 has Report Year as Primary Key, but Table 2 doesn't have that constraint.

Table1:

```
Report Year
2013 LTP
2014 LTP
2015 LTP
2016 LTP
2017 LTP
2018 LTP
2019 LTP
2020 LTP
2020 6+6
2021 LTP
2022 4+8
2022 BP
2022 LTP
BP19
BP20
```

Table2:

```
Report Year
2013 LTP
2014 LTP
2014 LTP
2015 LTP
2016 LTP
2017 LTP
2018 LTP
2018 LTP
2018 LTP
2019 LTP
2020 LTP
2020 LTP
2020 LTP
2020 6+6
2021 LTP
2022 4+8
2022 BP
2022 LTP
2020 6+6
2020 LTP
2020 6+6
2021 LTP
2022 4+8
2022 LTP
2022 LTP
2022 LTP
BP19
BP20
BP20
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: @Wouter i updated my post

Comment: Can you do something like this? update [Table1]
set [Report Year] = LEFT([Report Year], 4)

Comment: @Brandon interesting, could explain what that does?

Comment: @Brandon also, some of the report years i want to retain the LTP suffix with them, so any report year after 2018 that has LTP should remain with LTP. only years prior to 2019 should have LTP removed

Comment: It just trims the report year down to the first four characters...you could add a where clause to the update statement to limit it to the rows you want to update update [Table1] set [Report Year] = LEFT([Report Year], 4) WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Report Year], 4)) < 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first 4 characters from `ReportYear` and check if its a number. If so, convert those 4 digits to an integer and limit the selection to years before 2019. Update the selection by changing the `ReportYear` to the first 4 characters of that column.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  ReportYear nvarchar(10)
);

insert into MyTable (ReportYear) values
('2013 LTP'),
('2014 LTP'),
('2015 LTP'),
('2016 LTP'),
('2017 LTP'),
('2018 LTP'),
('2019 LTP'),
('2020 LTP'),
('2020 6+6'),
('2021 LTP'),
('2022 4+8'),
('2022 BP'),
('2022 LTP'),
('BP19'),
('BP20');
```

**Solution**

```
update mt
set mt.ReportYear = left(mt.ReportYear, 4)
from MyTable mt
where isNumeric(left(mt.ReportYear, 4)) = 1
  and try_convert(int, left(mt.ReportYear, 4)) < 2019;
```

Details and working example: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85e395e2bb48ab5e777f974862b68ba4).

Comment: interesting, what does this do?

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
case when [Report Year] not like '%2019 LTP%'
     and  [Report Year] not like '%20[23456789][0123456789] LTP%' -- tweak as necessary
    then replace([Report Year], ' LTP', '')
    else [Report Year]
end
```

This will work until the end of the century. It deals with text as text without needing to attempt casts to a numeric type.

An alphabetic comparison might even be good enough based on your sample data. This one also handles the year dynamically:

```
case when [Report Year] < cast(year(getdate() - 1) as char(4))
    then replace([Report Year], ' LTP', '')
    else [Report Year]
end
```

Comment: wait doesnt this mean it impacts years greater than 2019 as well? i only want to change the years listed in my replace(), which are the years less than 2019 only

Comment: @Cataster, that's easy enough to adjust.

Comment: Does this logic need to change automatically next year?

Comment: good question. it may, because LTP stands for long term planning, and so since 2018 and below years are no longer forecasting years, thats why we had to remove LTP from them. i assume we'll have to do this in the future to years that are gone by then